# Language URL Redirects to original path when trailing slash is missing

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm currently looking at setting up a few paths for multi language on our site.

I'm wanting to route it through the same php files and just load in a different content file depending on the url structure.

I've been using:

`RewriteRule ^(es|fr|us)/(.*)$ /$2 [QSA,L]`

Which works well however if the url doesnt have a trailing slash it reverts back. These are virtual folders and just route to the correct index.php file.

For example:

`www.example.com/es/signup/` - This works and keeps the url in place

`www.example.com/es/signup` - without the trailing slash redirects back to www.example.com/signup/ (missing the language path)

Intended outcome would be that www.example.com/es/signup redirects to www.example.com/es/signup/ as well

I've had a look at the redirect log and can't see anything obvious.

I could be wrong but I think it might be due to the directoryslashes setting with Apache? when signup/ is passed over it hits the directory however if signup (without the trailing slash) is passed over it does the 301 redirect due to the directoryslashes setting?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A little bit unclear what you want, **however**:

```
RewriteRule ^(es|fr|us)/(.*)$ /$2 [QSA,L]
```

Takes:

```
www.example.com/es/route
```

And turns it into:

```
www.example.com/route
```

The:

```
www.example.com/es/route
```

That redirects to:

```
www.example.com/es/route/
```

**Is default behavior** to achieve it, simply delete the above rule.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ye that sounds correct and it's all working fine however when the trailing slash is missing at the end it reverts back to the url without the language.

For example:

/es/route/ - In the url bar it shows /es/route/ but is using /route/index.php (without the language path)

/es/route (missing trailing slash) - It gets 301 redirected back to just /route/. The url bar just shows /route/ and I have no way of detecting the language.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I told you that's because you have that RewriteRule. That's what it does. Get rid of it and it will be okay.

Comment: As I understood you thought it's doing the opposite, but it does exactly the thing you seemingly don't need. Try without it, erase the cache restart the server and update who's it going.

Comment: Hi vitali. Sorry I think there's probably some miscommunication here. If i remove the rewrite rule then the page 404s. The /es/ folder doesn't exist. It's almost just a virtual route for language support. Everything will be going through the one file.

In your example above www.example.com/es/route doesn't redirect to www.example.com/es/route/ it redirects to www.example.com/route. That is my issue. If the trailing slash isn't present then it goes back down to the previous sub-directory. I was presuming this was something to do with the directoryslashes  and might just need a rule update.

Comment: Please read about regexes and regular expressions. That is exactly what I'm explaining. To make /es/route to redirect to /es/route/ **delete** this rule. Of course es/ might not exist if you haven't implement them, but once you delete this rule, you'll be forwarded from route to route/. This is the **default** behavior :)

Comment: You see this "/$2" in your rule? It takes the suffix, which is /route and whenever /es/ presents, it erases /es/ and applies /route instead without the /es/. It does DOES NOT add /. When there is no /es/, default behavior applies and ...com/route turns to .com/route/, since route/ is an existing directory in **that** path. Okay? It's easy, take a look at it after some refressh on the material. I promise you'll understand.

Comment: You can also make `^(es|fr|us)/(.*)$ /$2` be `^(es|fr|us)/(.*)/*$ /$2/` AND it will solve your problem, but that'll be a poop.